Unity IAP, Multi-quantity: Billing library version 4.0+ is required to use this feature
I am trying to setup Unity IAP for google play store, whenever I create an in-app product,
the multi-quantity check mark is disabled,
"Billing library version 4.0+ is required to use this feature"
Using unity IAP 4.22.2
unity 2022.3.18f
target SDK tried both 31 and 34
Tried adding dependencies manually to mainTemplate.grade,
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:5.0.0' // Google Play Billing Library
cleaned cache for a clean build but still didn't work.
Screen Shot of issue
Edit:
I was able to fix this problem, leaving this for anyone going through the same issue.
I have Custom Main Gradle template enabled. Make sure to add this to your mainTemplate.gradle:
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.billingclient:billing:6.2.1'
    }
}

